# Cron schedule from 7:15am to 8:30pm at every minute

Tags: cron

I can't find any material on how to create hours with minute components within a single expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to run this particular `cron` job in just a single expression, but it could be done in three:

```
15-59 7 * * * echo "This command runs every minute from 7:15am to 7:59am"
0-59 8-19 * * * echo "This command runs every minute from 8:00am to 7:59pm"
0-30 20 * * * echo "This command runs every minute from 8:00pm to 8:30pm"
```

POSIX `cron` allows you to use dashes (`-`) to define a range of units (`0-59`), or commas (`,`) to define a list of units (`0,2,4,6,8`). Some `cron` variants also allow using slashes (`/`) to define evenly recursing units (`*/15` is the same as `0,15,30,45`).

Unfortunately, none of those work when you have an unusual beginning and end like your example does.